# Create object-properties from an array

Tags: javascript, array, properties

I'm writing a simple table-oriented storage for objects. The schema of a table is stored in the `columns`-array and the data in the `rows`-array.

```
// example: table "employees"
var columns = ["id", "name"]
var rows = [[1, "Alice"], [2, "Bob"]];
```

I wrote a function to convert a row-array into an object:

```
function convertRowToObject(row) {
    var result = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) result[columns[i]] = row[i];
    return result;
}
```

Now I can get an employee-object where I can access the fields by name, not by index.

```
// [1, "Alice"] -> { id: 1, name: "Alice" }
```

Is there any way to get the `convertRowToObject` function any smaller? I think there should be a way to get rid of the loop and make this with a single line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make it smaller by turning your function into a constructor:

```
function RowObject(row) {
    for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) 
      this[columns[i]] = row[i];
}
```

You would have to call this function with `new` then. I would avoid putting the assignment on the same line as the `for`, it is too Golfic to maintain.

The only way to avoid a loop is to fake it:

```
function convertRowToObject2(row) {
  //o -> object, v -> value, i -> index
  return row.reduce( function(o, v, i){ o[columns[i]] = v; return o; } , {} );
}
```

Comment: I like the one-liner, but the compiler will not know that he can handle the elements of the array independently, hence I will not be executed in parallel, as it can be done with map for example.